# Handle Jedis timeout

Tags: groovy, redis, timeout, jedis

I have a Groovy script that uses the Jedis API. Once in a while, the Jedis client times out. I understand that timeout is by default set to 2000 and it can be customized.  But I'm wondering if there is a way to handle this exception so that the timeout error can be dealt with gracefully without the app crashing.

Code where Jedis is called:

```
use(TimerMethods) {
        // Connect to Redis
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis(redisHost, redisPort)

        def timer = new Timer()
        def task = timer.runEvery(1000, interval * 1000) {
            def redisHosts = jedis.lrange(key, 1, -1)
               marathonHosts.each {
            if (!redisHosts.contains(it)) {
                jedis.rpush(key, it)
                log.info("Added new host $it for $key in Redis")
            }
        }
    }
}


Exception in thread "Timer-0" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:79)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:199)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:192)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.lrange(Jedis.java:955)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
at BridgeSynchronizer.sync(Bridge.groovy:112)
at BridgeSynchronizer$sync$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at BridgeSynchronizer.syncApps(Bridge.groovy:139)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:368)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
at BridgeSynchronizer$_runBridge_closure5_closure13.doCall(Bridge.groovy:163)
at BridgeSynchronizer$_runBridge_closure5_closure13.doCall(Bridge.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:901)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:166)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeClosure(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:572)
at GroovyTimerTask.run(Bridge.groovy:175)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:108)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.fill(RedisInputStream.java:109)
at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:45)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:64)
... 38 more
```

Comment: Some of your code would undoubtedly help

Comment: What you want is automatic reconnection? Did you check using a JedisPool of one connection? If jedis fails, JedisPool will spawn a new safe jedis instance if possible in the back scene without you checking the exception (it is a pool after all).